# Reference variable whose value is assigned inside block

Tags: ios, swift, scope, closures, block

Hi had a confusion on what is the scope of the value that is assigned to outside ref variable inside a completion block. For example in the below code will the values of operationError and savedRecords persist outside of completion block.

```
    func applyLocalChangesToServer(insertedOrUpdatedCKRecords:Array<CKRecord>,deletedCKRecordIDs:Array<CKRecordID>) throws
    {
        var savedRecords:[CKRecord]?
        var conflictedRecords:[CKRecord] = [CKRecord]()
        var removeRecords:[CKRecord] = [CKRecord]()
        var operationError : NSError?

        let ckModifyRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave:insertedOrUpdatedCKRecords, recordIDsToDelete: deletedCKRecordIDs);
        ckModifyRecordsOperation.atomic = true
        ckModifyRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = ({(savedRecords1,deletedRecordIDs1,error)->Void in

            operationError = error

            if error == nil
            {
                wasSuccessful = true
                savedRecords = savedRecords1
            }
            else
            {
                wasSuccessful = false
                savedRecords = nil
                errorCKS = self.handleError(error!)
            }

        })
        ckModifyRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = ({(ckRecord,error)->Void in

            if error != nil
            {  
                if error!.code == CKErrorCode.ServerRecordChanged.rawValue
                {
                    conflictedRecords.append(ckRecord!)
                }
            }

        })

        self.operationQueue?.addOperation(ckModifyRecordsOperation)
        self.operationQueue?.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()

        if conflictedRecords.count > 0  
        {
            //Do work here

        }
        else if operationError != nil //Other then the partial error
        {
            throw operationError
        }

}
```

Note: Had assign operationError since the func applyLocalChangesToServer throws an error and is inside a while loop.

Comment: Why are you blocking and waiting? Why don't you call another function from the completion block?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, these variables defied in the enclosure scope will be modified after the completion handler is performed. So you code should work as expected.

Comment: One observation - self.operationQueue has to be set before the method invocation. I would recommend to add check in the code and throw, if the queue wasn't set.

Comment: @wain I need to call this function repeatedly till all conflicts are resolved so either i have to call this function recursively or use inside a while loop.

Comment: @ignor B. So their value will persist right till the scope of applyLocalChangesToServer  function. Okaies will add the check.

Comment: @user3519594 Right. My account name is Igor B. - that's why I missed you comment - I didn't receive an notification :)

Comment: @Igor B. Thanks for the help. Was really confused for the memory thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, these variables defied in the enclosure scope will be modified after the completion handler is performed. So you code should work as expected.

Also you can use following:

```
ckModifyRecordsOperation.main()
```

instead of:

```
self.operationQueue?.addOperation(ckModifyRecordsOperation)
self.operationQueue?.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ignor the confusion i had was about the life time of operationError variable since it is assigned inside the completion handler are their any chances that it may get nil somehow. i.e say the operationError = error points to the error variable now if closure handles the lifetime of error it may get nilled and operationError may point to nil. sorry this is a silly question but am still confused about the memory management for closure

Comment: @user3519594 If type of the error object is a `reference` type then you are good, as references in Swift are `strong` by default. It means when you assign `error` to `operationError` the error object reference counter is retained. So that error object won't be deallocated till `operationError` is set to `nil` or it's scope is ended - `applyLocalChangesToServer()` is performed. If type of the error object is a `value` type then you are good too, as `operationError` has a copy of the error object => lifetime of initial error object does not affect you copy.